# How to populate inherited MPTT fields while creating a Django fixture?

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I'm following the instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) to create my first Django fixture. I've created a JSON file. But there is a complication: The model I'm trying to populate inherits from `MPTTModel`

Here is what my Django JSON fixture file `initial_data.json` looks like:

```
[
    {
         "model": "MyApp.MyModel", 
         "pk": 1, 
         "fields": {
             "level": 0, 
             "parent": null, 
             "name": "My String"
         }
    }
]
```

When I run this fixture, I get the error shown below. It turns out there are a handful of other fields that must be defined in the fixture for this model: `rght`, `lft`, `tree_id`, `level`.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture    
'MyApp/fixtures/initial_data.json': Could not load MyApp.MyModel(pk=1): 
    null value in column "lft" violates not-null constraint
Failing row contains (1, My String, null, , null, null, null, 0).
```

I can figure out what the `level` attribute is supposed to be and insert it into the fixture file. But how am I supposed to figure out and set the values of `rght`, `lft`, `tree_id` in the this fixture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how did you create the fixture, manually? using the dumpdata command should give you a clear view of the required structure, here's an example of a mptt inheriting model json dump:

```
$ ./manage.py dumpdata cms.Page --natural --indent=4
[
    {
        "pk": 46,
        "model": "cms.page",
        "fields": {
            "rght": 43,
            "navigation_extenders": "",
            "site": 1,
            "creation_date": "2014-05-31T12:07:12Z",
            "lft": 42,
            "in_navigation": false,
            "reverse_id": null,
            "login_required": false,
            "created_by": "hedde",
            "publication_end_date": null,
            "template": "cms/page.html",
            "tree_id": 2,
            "placeholders": [
                159,
                160
            ],
            "changed_date": "2014-06-25T09:33:50Z",
            "limit_visibility_in_menu": null,
            "parent": 2,
            "publisher_state": 0,
            "soft_root": false,
            "publication_date": "2014-05-31T12:07:07Z",
            "publisher_public": 45,
            "level": 1,
            "changed_by": "hedde",
            "publisher_is_draft": false,
            "published": true
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was creating my fixture manually, yes. After your post, I loaded my data into the DB and then created the fixture using ./manage.py dumpdata